# In R - Convert for loop into apply and sapply

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, apply, sapply

I have some nested for-loops but I do have difficulties in converting the first (and or second) for loop into apply and sapply. I would want to convert some of the code using apply and sapply (I don't want to be using cumsum for this). Has anyone an idea on how to convert this.

```
m <- array(runif(100,1,10),dim=c(4,5,10))
result <- array(NA,dim=c(dim(m)))


for(k in 1:10) {
for(n in 1:4) {   
for(j in 1:ncol(m)) {
for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {
result[n,j,k] <- sum(m[n:i,j,k]) 
break} 
}
}
}
```

Here's what I tried, but somehow got stuck.

```
apply(m,3,function(x) 
for(n in 1:4) {   
for(j in 1:ncol(m)) {
for(i in 1:nrow(m)) {
result[n,j,x] <- sum(m[n:i,j,x]) 
break} 
}
}
})
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: It is very easy to work with `cumsum`.  ie. `apply(m, c(2,3), cumsum)`  Why you want to do it with loops?

Comment: That is a very strange sequence of for loops. Sometimes `n:i` will generate a decreasing sequence of indices, and you're assigning to each combination of `n,j,k` four times and only keeping the last one.

Comment: @akrun. Because in my real example I will also work with additional thresholds and I am trying to understand combining loops with apply. joran: I was trying to prevent this by breakting the most inner loop I thought.

Comment: The `i`-loop does absolutely nothing; only results for `i=4` are reported. Anyway, the `apply` statement that returns the same as your loop would be `apply(m, c(2, 3), function(mat){ rev(cumsum(rev(mat))) })`.

Comment: I assumed the `break` statement was simply a mistake, because as shadow says there's no point to a for loop that you execute only once. Just do `n:1`, but again, it would be best if you provided something that was closer to your real goal.